# Angular filter, when there are no items show text

Tags: angularjs

If a array of items is filtered and there are no items that match I would like to show 'No items'.

```
vm.items = [
  {name: '1', type: 1},
  {name: '2', type: 2},
  {name: '1.2', type: 1},
];

<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter: {type:1}>
     {{item.name}}
   </li>
   <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter: {type:1} ?? length === 0>
      No items
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you could use `ng-if` directive with `filtered.length` data of `ng-repeat` with its alias

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in vm.items | filter: {type:1} as filtered">
     {{item.name}}
   </li>
   <li ng-if="!filtered.length">
      No items
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There are 10 item from which there are 5 of type = 1. Your answer would only be right when all items are of type 1.

Comment: @RalfdeKleine check updated answer please, downvoter please look at the updated answer

Comment: Ok this answers my question :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat trick to remember the count of filters:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in (filtered = vm.items | filter: {type:1})>
     {{item.name}}
   </li>
   <li ng-if="filtered.length == 0">
      No items
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok this answers my question :)